# dual boot window in startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

Recently I have updated my windows operation system (windows 8.1).

But after that the dual boot option in start-up has vanished and now it's only possible to boot into windows.

How can I manage dual boot option like before I updated my OS?

I used `easy-bcd`, but there are some problems occurring in my Ubuntu system. That's why I uninstalled that.

Note: the Ubuntu (13.04) is in another partition of hard drive. So there is no chance that it was deleted.

Please can you give me a better solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had windows 8.1 installed and I had few problems, you should try doing the following:
1) Use easy-bcd to get your Ubuntu option back
2) when in Ubuntu, just open a terminal and type in: 'sudo update-grub' (it will make grub your default boot loader, if you have burg install type in 'sudo update-burg')
3) Disable Windows 8.1 fast boot (http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-8-restart-and-shutdown-problems-by-disabling-hybrid-shutdown-feature/), fast boot will make ubuntu unable to access your windows partitions